# C# How can I add a system.diagnostics source listener programmatically?

Tags: c#, wcf, logging

how can I do the following programatically?  We want to be able to turn it on from UI setting screen, and also, don't want to require admin privileges to update the App.config file. Thank you

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traceListener"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData= "C:\Temp\WCF_UI_Trace.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the following classes: **XmlWriterTraceListener**, **TraceSource**.

**XmlWriterTraceListener**: It belongs
**System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll**. It can write some data to the svclog file. [XmlWriterTraceListener Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener?view=net-8.0)

**TraceSource**: t belongs
**System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll**. It provides a set of methods and properties that enable an application to track the execution of code and associate a trace message with its source. [TraceSource Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracesource?view=net-7.0)

```
 public class Service : IService
    {
    public void Test()
    {
        
        XmlWriterTraceListener TestListener = new XmlWriterTraceListener("TestListener.svclog");

        
        TraceSource TestSource = new TraceSource("TestSource");

        
        TestSource.Listeners.Add(TestListener);

        
        TestSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;

        
        TestSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "Entering Test");

       

        TestSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 2, "Exiting Test");

        
        TestListener.Flush();
        TestListener.Close();
    }
}
```